# Auto increment column which resets every year

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a database (MySql) of certificates, each one identified by a code, in this format:

`year`-`number`

where Year is the last two digits of the year where the certificate was obtained and Number is an incremental number o five digits (ex. `14-12345`). Every year, the Number part must reset. So the first certificate of 2015 will be 15-00001.
My problem is with the "Number" part of the code. By now I'm doing this:

```
SELECT MAX(Number) FROM certificates WHERE Year = YEAR(NOW())
```

Then, in a separate statement in my application, something like this (pseudo code to simplify):

```
INSERT INTO certificates (Year, Number) VALUES (YEAR(NOW()), ++Number)
```

inside a loop, to insert multiple new certificates.

This works, but is not so safe in terms of concurrent insertions. Maybe I could use a transaction, but I think there's a better way.

I think of an auto-increment value in another table and a foreign key inside the main table, but I don't know how to reset at each year change.

Comment: Use an auto-incremented integer for the primary key of the table.  Make the certificate code another column that you maintain via a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an autoincrement field (ID) in the table Certificates (probably you already have one for the key), and a table where you collect informations about the last ID inserted every year (LastIDYear).

Your year-number field is a calculated field where the number part is:

ID -(last year inserted ID) . The last year inserted ID is found in the additional table above (LastIDYear). You can join the tables on the year columns to find all the information you need.

You could have missing number in the sequence.. but I think is not mandatory to have a complete sequence in the year-number certificate description.

Comment: MySql doesn't support computed columns (I think) but you put me on the right way. I could make a view for this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

every new year the first time you perform your query:

```
SELECT MAX(Number) FROM certificates WHERE Year = YEAR(NOW())
```

the result will be a `NULL`.
add a check and where you get a `NULL` you put a 1 instead.